# What does "though" mean in these sentences?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english

I knew these are American English sentences, and they are informal. However, I would like to know what exactly it means, or it simply means nothing, and people merely want to add something unnecessary at the end of a sentence, because it sounds fetch.

Sentences like:

> 1. His denim jacket, though.
> 2. I love the way he talks, though.
> 3. For real, though.
> 4. Really, though.
> 5. What's up though
> 6. When are you coming over, though?

Comment: At http://www.thefreedictionary.com/though are different senses in which _though_ is used. The AHD gives the informal, intensifier usage that is really just like an exclamation mark (it labels it an adverb here, whereas I'd prefer pragmatic marker subclass emphasiser): **though** 2. (Informal) Used as an intensive: _Wouldn't that beat all, though?_ Not enough context (a prior sentence, say) is given above to decide on the type of usage here; (4) certainly looks like an example of this usage. Collins doesn't give this usage, but I seem to remember it from old British novels.

Comment: Either they're contrasting the sentence with something in a previous sentence, or they signify that the speaker is changing the subject, or they're intensifiers, or they mean something else. ***We need more context.*** A possible example of the first usage is *"I don't think his boots look good on him. His denim jacket, though."*

Comment: "Though" as an indicator of contrast in most of these cases is on target. For example: "For real, though" is a statement I can see as an addendum to another statement or question, precluding the possibility of the respondent's NOT saying something "for real." This would be as in, "Do you eat worms? For real, though." This means, "I know you might give me a fake answer (a lie), but I don't want that. Tell me your real answer (the truth)."

Comment: By the way, is "fetch" now being used as a adjective? If so, what does it mean?

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sir_24duiF4

Comment: ... Urban Dictionary has: Slang word that a "plastic" in Mean Girls tried to popularize. Just another way to say _cool_.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg Lol, sorry it was from Mean Girls. haha. I don't know, though. It's funny.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 incomplete sentence
2-6 It implies a contrast.

"He's a bit of an idiot. I love the way he walks, though."

**EDIT:**
I've recently heard phrases like the OP's #1 *His denim jacket, though*

It's slang, but the best way I could put logic to it is that it implies that one could notice a lot of things about this person, but the jacket supersedes all other noticeable traits. (Thus, the comparison) It can be used as a compliment or put-down.

*Those shoes thoough!* (A ragged pair of sneakers or a fancy pair of snake skin business shoes.)

This goes along with @Edwin Ashworth's comment.